# IRedisClient not disposed after using

Tags: redis, servicestack

I am using an ServiceStack IRedis client as follows

```
public static IRedisList<MyType> getList(string listkey)
{
   using(var redis = new RedisClient())
   {
      var client = redis.As<MyType>();
      return client.Lists[listkey];
   }

}


public void AddSomething(MyType newType)
{
   var list = getList("somekey);
   list.Add(newType);.

}
```

according to the Redis-Server output, everytime I do this a new client connection is added, and it never is getting disposed. (Client count is always increasing).

Should I not be manipulating the `IRedisList` as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IRedisList` is like a **proxy** wrapper for a redis server-side list which includes a reference to the **RedisClient** it was created with in order to talk Redis.

The `using(var redis = new RedisClient()) { ... }` statement does dispose of the Client connection, unfortunately when you make any further calls with the Disposed client it re-opens the connection again and since it isn't in a using statement or not manually disposed will keep the connection open.

To prevent this from happening, you should not be accessing the RedisList proxy outside of the using scope of the RedisClient in which it was created. If you still want to reference the list outside of this scope you should clone the contents into an In-Memory list with:

```
var disconnectedInMemoryCopy = client.Lists[listKey].ToList();
```

This returns a populated normal C# `List<T>` that's de-coupled from the RedisList proxy.

Comment: okay, so I should then specifically open and close the using to perform actions on the Redis List? Would it be better to maybe expose a implementation that allows this behavior?

Comment: The idea is not hang on to, or access the redis list outside the scope of the RedisClient. I'm not sure what can be added to the API to help here?

Comment: sorry not to the api, I meant from my end creating a IList implementation that keeps the in memory and redis lists in sync